# wxMP3gain equivalent for FLAC files

Tags: windows, gratis, audio, gui, flac

I need an easy-to-use program that supports lossless volume normalization for FLAC files.

I'm aware of programs like MP3gain and wxMP3gain, but these—surprise, surprise—only support MP3 files.

By "easy-to-use", I mean basically plug-and-play: you choose the folder(s) or file(s), press "Go", and kaboom it works. I'm not experienced in audio processing or anything like that, and I don't want to have to deal with command-line stuff even if there's a program out there that does all this but requires command-line.

I would prefer this to be FOSS, but it doesn't have to be.

It most certainly has to be gratis.

#### Specs

- **Make & Model**: Lenovo G50-45
- **Operating System**: Windows 10 Home 64-Bit

Comment: This one says it batch normalizes FLAC, never used it...http://www.kanssoftware.com/programs.htm

Comment: DBPowerAmp also does what you want...https://forum.dbpoweramp.com/showthread.php?10433-Normalize-existing-FLAC-collection-with-dbpowerAMP

Comment: You should include this as an answer...

Comment: I don't want to buy the software to do screenshots....

Comment: I should have mentioned I want it to be gratis. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

For a GUI solution you could use [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/download/) but with the proviso that it will work on one file at a time by default.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform - builds available for Windows, OS-X & Linux
- Supports multiple formats including FLAC
- You could write a [plug-in](http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Creating_your_own_Plug-in) using Batch Chains to Normalise all of the selected files or a directory worth of files.
- GUI based
- Can do a lot more of course.

For anybody who is not so averse to the command line see the SU question and answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/323119/how-can-i-normalize-audio-using-ffmpeg) for a mechanism that would let you type `ffmpeg-normalize *.flac` in a directory full of such files - of course you could always add a file/directory select GUI to the solution given there will a little effort.

### Update

In fact there is an [chains example](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/chains_for_batch_processing_and_effects_automation.html##Example_1:_LoudMP3) Example 1 that fits you case well.

### Constructing a Chain

To construct the chain that you need:

1. start Audacity with nothing loaded
2. select `File->Edit Chains...` and you get a window like:[image]
3. On the bottom left select `Add` and you will be prompted for the name, *give it one that makes sense to you and click `OK`*:
   [image]
4. Click `Insert` and you will get the Select Command pop-up, Pick `Normalize` and if you feel the need play with the parameters by selecting `Edit Parameters`, *the defaults look quite sensible to me* then click `OK`: 
   [image]
5. Make sure `-END-` is still selected and then Click `Insert` again and pick your export, *presumably ExportFLAC*:
   [image]
6. Your "Edit Chains" window should now look something like the following, if it does click `OK`:
   [image]

### Using you new chain

1. Open Audacity with no files loaded *if it is not already open* if any files are loaded select `File->Close`
2. Select `File->Apply Chains...` and on the dialog select your new chain and select `Apply to Files` and then in the file select dialog navigate to the files you wish to convert and select those files.

[image]

1. Depending on the number of files that you selected do one of: watch it in action, go and have a cup of tea, go and have a meal, go to bed for the night.
2. Find your new files in a sub-directory of the original called `cleaned`

### Important Note

The **good news** is that your original files are not overwritten so they are safe, the **bad news** is that your original files are not overwritten so the disk space taken **doubles!** I would recommend running on smallish directories of your music/sounds at a time, checking the results to make **sure** that you are happy, then moving the originals to backup media.

Comment: I don't know how to program, so I don't think I could write a plug-in. Are you sure Audacity doesn't at least support bulk selection, even if it only does one file at a time? Also, I've tried Audacity before and the gui seems extremely novice-unfriendly.

Comment: @SarahofGaia - Audacity does allow you to open more than one file at a time, then each opens in it's own window.

Comment: @SarahofGaia I have added a step by step guide above on how to create and use a suitable chain.

Comment: Thanks! Wow, that took dedication to make that whole guide! I'll try it out after I sleep. :)

Comment: Also, no worries about the doubling space. I've got a 1 TB hard drive. ^-^

Comment: @SarahofGaia - 1 TB is handy but not if you have 999 GB of FLAC files or even 1.2 GB of FLACs and 998 GB of other stuff. Also I try to keep in mind that other people may come along later who may not have plenty of space.

Comment: That is true enough, I suppose.