# Does anyone know a free and lossless 'audio volume normalizer' with a spectograph or sth else useful?

Tags: audio-editing

(so that I can check to see if it's good before I convert/write)

(If anyone knows one that only works for mid and flac files that's good enough:)

[P.S. please don't suggest audacity, for the love of god...]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wxMP3gain equivalent for FLAC files](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31285/wxmp3gain-equivalent-for-flac-files)

Comment: @karel I wish it did but thanks for the link.